# Shortening query: Percentage of successful attentions per doctor per year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with the following view:

[image]

It shows the number of successful attention performed by a given doctor, per year.

Now I want to create a query that gives the percentage of successful attentions from the total number of attentions (since he was hired), divided per year. That is [Successful Attentions 1996]/[Total Attentions]

In someway I've of done that, but I don't like the script I wrote:

```
SELECT tv1.Doc_ID, Y1996, Y1997, Y1998, Y1999, Y2000, Y2001
FROM
(
    SELECT  Doc_ID, CAST(1.00*[Successful 1996]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y1996
    FROM VIEW3
) tv1,
(
    SELECT  Doc_ID, CAST(1.00*[Successful 1997]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y1997
    FROM VIEW3
) tv2,
(
    SELECT  Doc_ID, CAST(1.00*[Successful 1998]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y1998
    FROM VIEW3
) tv3,
(
    SELECT  Doc_ID, CAST(1.00*[Successful 1999]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y1999
    FROM VIEW3
) tv4,
(
    SELECT  Doc_ID, CAST(1.00*[Successful 2000]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y2000
    FROM VIEW3
) tv5,
(
    SELECT  Doc_ID, CAST(1.00*[Successful 2001]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y2001
    FROM VIEW3
) tv6
WHERE tv1.doc_id=tv2.doc_id
AND tv1.doc_id=tv3.doc_id
AND tv1.doc_id=tv4.doc_id
AND tv1.doc_id=tv5.doc_id
AND tv1.doc_id=tv6.doc_id
```

I basically created separate tables for every year and then join them, but the fact of having to repeat the query doesn't look that nice. I was trying to use the CASE...THEN...ELSE statement but it gives an error.

Is the CASE...THEN...ELSE the way to write a shorter query? Whether yes or not, How I

Comment: Why don't just select them as normal way? `select Doc_ID, Cast(1.00*[Successful 1996]/[Total Attentions] as decimal(10, 2)), Cast(1.00*[Successful 1997]/[Total Attentions] as decimal(10, 2))
from View3`?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply select them together, no need to divide selection, if you are selecting form same view.

```
SELECT Doc_ID, 
CAST(1.00*[Successful 1996]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y1996,
CAST(1.00*[Successful 1997]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y1997,
CAST(1.00*[Successful 1998]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y1998,
CAST(1.00*[Successful 1999]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y1999,
CAST(1.00*[Successful 2000]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y2000,
CAST(1.00*[Successful 2001]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Y2001
FROM VIEW3
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I missed something in your question, but what you are doing basically boils down to:

```
SELECT
    doc_id,
    Y1996=CAST(1.00*[Successful 1996]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)),
    Y1997=CAST(1.00*[Successful 1997]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)),
    Y1998=CAST(1.00*[Successful 1998]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)),
    Y1999=CAST(1.00*[Successful 1999]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)),
    Y2000=CAST(1.00*[Successful 2000]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2)),
    Y2001=CAST(1.00*[Successful 2001]/[Total Attentions] AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM
    VIEW3
ORDER BY
    doc_id;
```

That is, if the `Doc_Id` is a primary key or unique index (i.e. each Doc_Id only occurs at most once in your source table).